# Tensorflow variable dynamic size in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

The output layer of my CNN should use the RBF function, described as "each neuron outputs the square of the Euclidean distance between its input vector and its weight vector". I've implemented this as

```
dense2 = tf.square(tf.norm(dense1 - tf.transpose(dense2_W)))
```

where `dense1` is a tensor of shape `(?, 84)`. I've tried declaring `dense2_W`, the weights, as a variable of shape `(84, 10)` since it's doing number classification and should have 10 outputs. Running the code with a batch of 100 I get this error: `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [100,84] vs. [10,84]`. I believe it is due to the subtraction.

I train the network by iterating this code:

```
x_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
x_batch = tf.pad(x_batch, [[0,0],[2,2],[2,2],[0,0]]).eval()  # Pad 28x28 -> 32x32
sess.run(train_step, {X: x_batch, Y: y_batch})
```

and then test it using the entire test set, thus the batch size in the network must be dynamic.

How can I work around this? The batch size must be dynamic, as in `dense1`'s case, but I don't understand how to make a variable with dynamic size and transposing it (`dense2_W`).

Comment: I think your RBF formula is not correct - you only can subtract matrices that have the same shape. Matrices of shapes `[batch_size, 84]` and `[84, num_classes]` are simply not compatible (even if you transpose the second matrix), because `batch_size != num_classes`.

Comment: @JindraHelcl that's essentially what I'm trying to solve, is there some other way I can implement the RBF formula to avoid this issue?

Comment: First, the weight vector should have the same shape as the input vector (to enable us to compute the distance). Then, the output of your RBF will be a vector of shape `[batch_size]` (so scalar value for every data point). Now, for 10 output classes, you could have 10 of these RBFs, each one with different weights. You could achieve this by having `dense2_W` of shape `[84, num_classes]` and expanding dimensions of the input to `[batch, 84, 1]` to enable broadcasting. Maybe it will be necessary to also expand dims of the weight tensor to the batch axis.

Comment: If broadcasting won't work, you could stack the inputs `num_classes` times and use the stacked vector.

Comment: @JindraHelcl the input vector has size (?, 84) so when declaring the weights vector, which is a variable, it still needs a dynamic size which is what I asked about in the original question

Comment: Tensorflow can do broadcasting (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) so if you have two tensors whose shape differs in one dimension and if that dimension of one of the tensors is 1, you can still subtract/add them together and get expected results. So your weight matrix does not need to have a dynamic shape. You just need to add a batch dimension of size 1, which is achieved by `tf.expand_dims(..., axis=0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the shapes of the two tensors to match. Assuming you want to share the weights across the batch and also having separate set of weights for each output class, you could reshape both of the tensors in order to be correctly broadcasted, e.g:

```
# broadcasting will copy the input to every output class neuron
input_dense = tf.expand_dims(dense1, axis=2)

# broadcasting here will copy the weights across the batch
weights = tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(dense2_W), axis=0)

dense2 = tf.square(tf.norm(input_dense - weights, axis=1))
```

The resulting tensor `dense2` should have shape of `[batch_size, num_classes]`, which is `[100, 10]` in your case (so it will hold logits for every data instance over the number of output classes)

EDIT: added `axis` argument to the `tf.norm` call so that the distance is computed in the hidden dimension (not over the whole matrices).